# Undefined Office.context.ui in Outlook add-in

Tags: outlook-addin

I want to access `Office.context.ui.messageParent` as shown in the Dialog API example hosted in GitHub (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example), but `Office.context.ui` is undefined. I've searched for similar questions but either they haven't been answered or the answer hasn't worked for me.

If I `console.log( Office.context )` I get the following:

```
{}
    __proto__ :
        constructor : ƒ Object()
        hasOwnProperty : ƒ hasOwnProperty()
        isPrototypeOf : ƒ isPrototypeOf()
        propertyIsEnumerable : ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
        toLocaleString : ƒ toLocaleString()
        toString : ƒ toString()
        valueOf : ƒ valueOf()
        __defineGetter__ : ƒ __defineGetter__()
        __defineSetter__ : ƒ __defineSetter__()
        __lookupGetter__ : ƒ __lookupGetter__()
        __lookupSetter__ : ƒ __lookupSetter__()
        get __proto__ : ƒ __proto__()
        set __proto__ : ƒ __proto__()
```

Also tried to `console.log( Office.context.toString() )` but only got am `[object Object]`.

What do I have to do to properly load `Office.context.ui`?

Comment: What is the domain the app is pointing to and the domain you use in the dialog API?

Comment: Can you also make sure Office.Initialize on the dialog page is being called and that Office.context is not null?

Comment: The error went away when I removed some libraries. It's definitely not the best decision I've ever made, but it's working smooth now, just I don't know how. Namely, I've removed the `Office JavaScript API` and the `CDN` libraries that were included in the base code `yo` generated.

Still, I would like to solve this in a nicer way, but I might be less experienced in this field than required.

- What are domain app and the dialog API?

- What is the dialog page, so that I can check there both Office.Initialize and Office.context?

Comment: Well, you need Office.js reference, without which the API Office.context.ui.messageParent won't work. Could you paste the html and js code you have written for the page that's loaded in the dialog window?